# Where is the callback function of addEventListener stored in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, addeventlistener, event-listener, event-loop

I'm wondering where is the callback function of `addEventListener` stored.

In the [spec.whatwg](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#interface-eventtarget), they say like this,

> "Each EventTarget object **has an associated event listener list** (a list of zero or more event listeners). It is initially the empty list."

Is this all?

Then, how can we access that list by JavaScript ?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17238348/using-addeventlistener-to-add-a-callback-with-arguments it looks like it might help, I'm not too sure if that answers your question

Comment: You can not access the list of events attached to the element with JavaScript.

Comment: "*Is this all?*" - Is this not enough? And no, you cannot access this list from JavaScript, it's an implementation detail and there is no interface to expose it.